# Google speech to text bad quality on android chrome browser

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, socket.io, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm transferring audio streaming from Ionic app to Google speech to text API through web sockets node.js API. the accuracy in Desktop web app is good, but when I open the app from chrome mobile browser the accuracy was much worse. I tried another android browser and the result was great the same as desktop browsers!. Can anyone explain why this happened?

Comment: I guess this has to do with standard parameters for the AudioContext. Try to run exactly the same audio for all three and check the standard parameters for the browserslike the sample rate.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that Chrome uses MPEG-4 primarily whereas most Android use MIDI so you may need to convert using

```
def MPEG-4_to_MIDI(audio_file_name):
    if audio_file_name.split('.')[1] == 'MPEG-4':    
        sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(audio_file_name)
        audio_file_name = audio_file_name.split('.')[0] + '.MIDI'
        sound.export(audio_file_name, format="MIDI")
```

Comment: @omar attalah please inform me if this answer does not help you and so if yes, i can delete my answer to prevent wrongfuly claiming half your bounty

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not saving any files I transfer the streamed audio as a buffer to google api like the example here https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize